# Parse Server - Schema API to configure a new Parse instance

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

Does the opensource Parse Server include the Schema API for configuring a new Parse instance? I'm trying to eliminate the need to manually create apps.

This is the Schema API that was provided through Parse.com http://blog.parse.com/announcements/create-parse-apps-with-the-new-apps-api/

Answer (score -1):

Once you migrate, parse will automatically import all the necessary schema files.  Alternatively you could download your schmea file and import it yourself.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid a manual process of generating application through Linux commands. I could be creating 20+ apps a month.

Comment: Are your apps already created or will you be creating new apps?  If you already have apps created, just migrate them (through the parse dashboard) and your schema will automatically migrate with it.  If you are talking about new apps, the schema should create itself when you start writing to your db.  If this doesn't help, let me know and i'll stop posting :).

Comment: I have both to do. I already migrated one into my hosted parse server. But I'm more concerned on creating new apps. It seems I will have to manully update the cp ~parse/ecosystem.json ~parse/app_name.json for new app. Modify /etc/nginx/conf.d/url.conf  and then modify ~parse/parse-dashboard-config.json